# How does babel option ""auxiliaryCommentBefore" or "auxiliaryCommentAfter" work?

Tags: babeljs

I installed Babel(`"babel-cli": "^6.26.0"`) and and made a .babelrc like

```
{
  "auxiliaryCommentBefore": "testBefore",
  "auxiliaryCommentAfter": "testAfter"
}
```

and also made a simple test.js like

```
var a = 5;
```

and finally run `babel test.js`.

It secceded but no comment above is attached.. 
My expectation is something like below.

```
testBefore
var a = 5;
testAfter
```

Is there anything required missing??

Comment: Update: if I use "babel-preset-flow", it's not working. If I use "babel-preset-env", it's working.... is it intentionally?

Answer (score 0):

The honest answer to your question is "they don't" :D

The specific behavior of those two options are extremely under-defined and I would love to rip them out of Babel entirely, and I would except that I don't want to needlessly break existing users when they upgrade.

If you need to annotate some input code in a particular way, you should write your own Babel plugin to inject whatever you need instead.